# How to Factor a longer polynomial for Calc

Tags: calculus, factoring

So I'm working on a Calc problem and have to factor the following:

$ 12\left(x^3-x^2-x+1\right) $

This is Calc 1. I've factored quite a bit in algebra and calculus, but nothing like this. My professor ended up getting:

$ 12\left(x+1\right)\left(x-1\right)^2 $

...and I have no idea how. Is there a procedure I should know of, a rule for this sort of polynomial?

Comment: For third degree polynomials there is no definite method. In this case, it is quite obvious that $1$ is a root, so factor it out and then you have a quadratic left.

Comment: The only roots could be 1 or -1 (factors of the constant term 1).

Comment: A common technique is to use the method of rational roots. Here's a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$12\left(x^3-x^2-x+1\right)=12\left((x^3-x^2)-(x-1)\right)=12(x^2(x-1)-(x-1))$$
$$=12(x-1)(x^2-1)$$
$$=12(x-1)(x-1)(x+1)=12(x-1)^2(x+1)$$

Comment: Ah, I missed the difference of squares factorization of $\left(x^2−1\right)$ - Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

"Grouping":
\begin{align}
x^3 - x^2 - x + x & = \Big(x^3 - x^2\Big) - \Big(x-1\Big) \\[10pt]
& = x^2 \Big(x-1\Big) - 1\Big(x-1\Big) \\[10pt]
& = (x^2-1)(x-1) \\[10pt]
& = \cdots
\end{align}